# Why are 404 errors redirecting to my homepage and not my custom 404.php?

Tags: 404-error

Not sure if this strictly wordpress and not a general apache configuration but I'm having trouble setting up my 404 page for a custom theme.

I have my 404.php in the same directory as my index.php.

I had this working kind of working earlier by adding `ErrorDocument 404` with an explicit path to 404.php, but wordpress wasn't being included on the page. I've now removed that line.

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My apache enabled site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@seoplay.co.uk
        ServerName www.lart.co.uk
        ServerAlias lart.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lart.co.uk
        <Directory /var/www/lart.co.uk>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride FileInfo
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
         ..... etc
```

This is on a local machine.

I'm not sure how to make wordpress know about my custom 404 page.

Comment: Does the `404.php` work if you switch to a bundled theme like "Twenty Fourteen"?

Comment: @s_ha_dum thanks. Nope, it doesn't work with other themes either.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I've disabled all plugins too.

Comment: What is the redirect sequence? Watch the page load via something like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/).

Comment: @s_ha_dum just gave it a go, it gave me a 301 permanently moved, then a 200 ok response.

Comment: @s_ha_dum 
`00:00:36.891 0.170 294 304 GET 301 Redirect to: http://lart.co.uk/booogy/ http://lart.co.uk/booogy`